# Gruntfile to minify all HTML files of a folder?

Tags: html, gruntjs, minify

I’m using https://github.com/jney/grunt-htmlcompressor to compress HTML files. But it’s requiring me to manually type-in all the HTML files which I want minified:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  htmlcompressor: {
    compile: {
      files: {
        'dest/index.html': 'src/index.html'
      },
      options: {
        type: 'html',
        preserveServerScript: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Is there a way to specify that I want to minify all HTML files of the entire folder (and subfolders)?

Or, in case this html-compressor is limited, are you aware of a different npm package that does this HTML mification?

Comment: Please check this one https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin it may help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [glob pattern](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) should be allowed for any grunt task by default. Then simply use [dynamic files](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) to build each one to your dest

***Instead of***:

```
files: {
        'dest/index.html': 'src/index.html'
      },
```

**Go with:**

```
files: [
        {
          expand: true,     // Enable dynamic expansion.
          cwd: 'src/',      // Src matches are relative to this path.
          src: ['**/*.html'], // Actual pattern(s) to match.
          dest: 'dest/',   // Destination path prefix.
        },
      ],
```

As far as another plugin I would recommend [grunts contrib version](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compress) since it's more common and maintained by the grunt team.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compress is just for compressing, no? I want to minify HTML files (remove whitespace) not compress them.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I believe it should read minify html rather than compress in the title as they are 2 distinct operations. Glad I could help.

Comment: Great answer Ryan. Yes, agree - best to use: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin which is maintained by the Grunt team and regularly updated.